# ColdFusion-9 "includeEmptyValues"

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

This is my code:

```
returnStruct.myList = myList;
returnStruct.first = trim(ListGetAt(myList,3));
returnStruct.last = trim(ListGetAt(myList,13));
returnStruct.address = trim(ListGetAt(myList,15));
returnStruct.city = trim(ListGetAt(myList,2));
returnStruct.state = trim(ListGetAt(myList,9));
```

Everything is working fine until `myList` hits empty values and then everything crashes.
I found a command "includeEmptyValues" that I can set to 'yes' but I am not familiar with it and the documentation of ColdFusion 9 isn't the best I've come across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://cfquickdocs.com/cf9/#listgetat

Previous versions of ColdFusion (and CF9 by default) counted consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter. So a list that looked like this:

```
<cfset myList="a,b,,c,,d" />
```

was considered to have four elements.

Recently added is the "includeEmptyValues" attribute.

```
listGetAt(list, position [, delimiters, includeEmptyValues ])
```

So while

```
<cfset myVar=listGetAt(myList,6) />
```

will throw an error

```
<cfset myVar=listGetAt(myList,6,",","true") />
```

will successfully set `myVar` to `d`.

Answer (score 0):

might want to use listToArray(), and ArrayIsDefined().  Play with includeEmptyFields attr and see which behavior you prefer.  True = Convert empty elements in a list to empty array entries

Comment: Thanks for the advice but the comment above did the job just fine